# How to remove dataset on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie. I had similar block with dynamic background color, so I haven't exact background color, because it can be changed whenever. But I have static color in data attribute.
I want to add its attribute to my div on mouseenter and remove on mouseleave.
How can I do it?
My HTML code:

```
<div class="block" data-hover-bg="#a30003">
<div>
```

My js:

```
$( ".block" ).mouseenter(function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = this.dataset.hoverBg;
});
```

So how can I remove this dataset on mouseleave? And it should work repeatedly.

Thanks.

Comment: `this.style.backgroundColor = null`

Comment: I have a dynamic main background color for my css. So I can't set it to null.

Comment: not sure what you mean, but you can memorize the old color if you're clobbering it on mouseeneter, then re-apply it on mouseleave instead of null.

Comment: Is there another method? Something like remove last function effect?)

Comment: `this.style.boxShadow="0 0 0 99vw "+this.dataset.hoverBg+" inset";` looks like a background without touching the background property.

Comment: can't you just use classes and css?

Comment: No, it should be only js

Comment: Dandavis, I think your answer is the best solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another `data-*` attribute to remember the old background color:

```js
$( ".block" ).on({
  mouseenter() {
    $(this).data('hover-bg-old', $(this).css('background-color')); // Remember it
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('hover-bg'));
  },
  mouseleave() {
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('hover-bg-old')); // Reset it
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  padding: 30px;
  background: gold; /* Say this element already has a default background */
}
```

```html
<div class="block" data-hover-bg="#a30003">test</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

PS: in pure HTML `className` should be `class`

Comment: That was a type-o, sorry. is there simpler option? I have a lot of data attributes and multiple them all by two will be too many code.

Comment: @Aslan see this answer of mine from a couple of days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58465681/383904

Answer (score -1):

Here, you can dynamically add/remove background color on mouseover and mouseleave.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="block" data-hover-bg="#a30003" style="background-color: #dddddd">Text</div>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(".block").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).data('leave-bg', $(this).css('background-color'));
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('hover-bg'));
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('leave-bg'));
    $(this).removeData('leave-bg');
});
```

Comment: On mouseleave my background color will be null?

Comment: Yes, it removes style tag from your div and you can test in google inspect console, your div color goes normal as before, or if you want any default color you can set on mouseleave event.

Comment: I had before inline style on background color and its value is dynamic. So when I hover my div, inline style will take background color from data attribute. So in your example I will not have my previous background color on mouseleave, it will be null.